# TCPDF - No modificar PDF's

Tags: php, pdf

¿Cómo dejar sin permiso un *PDF* generado por *TCPDF* para modificar o copiar, etc?

Estos me interesaría dejar sin permiso:

- Ensamblaje de documento
- Extracción de página
- Comentarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta usando la función

```
setProtection()
```

por ejemplo:

```
$pdf->SetProtection($permissions = array('print', 'modify', 'copy', 'annot-forms', 'fill-forms', 'extract', 'assemble', 'print-high'), '', null, 0, null);
```

Aqui tienes el link a la documentacion de la funcion

https://tcpdf.org/docs/source_docs/classTCPDF/#a7ea250b2b4e3d7e55e657d52732a3b1d

Comment: Gracias amigo, esto era lo que estaba buscando.

Comment: Ok, de nada, si te fue util la respuesta considera marcarla como solucion a tu problema dando click en el check que esta debajo de la puntuacion de la respuesta, de esta manera mejoran las estadisticas del sitio, y otros usuarios pueden encontrar util tu pregunta.

Comment: Si, lo haré. Estoy probando con diferentes parámetros y revisando como quedan las propiedades de los archivos pdf. Una vez termine, lo haré.